# creating handle to objects in 2D/3D plot and manipulating them in python

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, animation

In Matlab, it is possible to create handle for say a square.

```
square = [2,-2; 2,2;-2,2;-2,-2];
sq_ = fill(square(:,1), square(:,2), 'g');
```

And then we can manipulate the object, say translate it from origin where it was to (17,81).

```
set(sq_, 'X', 17+square(:,1),'Y', 81+square(:,2));
```

The entire code to implement easily in Matlab is as follows:-

```
figure;
hold on
square = [2,-2; 2,2;-2,2;-2,-2];
sq_ = fill(square(:,1), square(:,2), 'g');
set(sq_, 'X', 17+square(:,1),'Y', 81+square(:,2));
```

How can we do the same in Python?

basically we are trying to move an object in the 2D plot according to our desire like animation. This can be extended to 3D also.

Please tell all ways of doing this in Python if there are multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: Why using `hold on`?

Comment: @EBH If the entire code chunk is run at once, then the translation is not clear. Instead running each line one by one shows that the square will translate. Hence `hold on` is needed because i intended the code to be run line-by-line. But a much better way would be to plot a scene much larger than the square and use `pause` to show the translation. But you are correct it is not needed.

Comment: @TheBlackCat I tried the `turtle` module showcased in Udacity course on Python. It seems to work but does not parallel the above approach of declaration of handles and then proceeding.